# How do I find out what version of TempleOS I am running?

Tags: version, templeos

On the [TempleOS site](http://www.templeos.org/), there is no mention of the current version. Wikipedia claims that [the latest current version of TempleOS is 5.03](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TempleOS). On [Twitter](https://archive.fo/fZG6o), the creator of the OS, Terry A. Davis, seems to indicate that it has a version number,

[image]

This reads,

> Released TempleOS V4.12. Kind-of cleaned up things.

**How can I identify the version of TempleOS that I am running?** What's the equivalent of `lsb_release -a`, `/etc/debian_version` and the like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version of TempleOS can be found by

### Top of the Terminal

You can always open a terminal with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

[image]

### Printing C variables

Defined in the file `C:\Kernel\KGlbls.HC.Z` which is executed by the kernel there are variables defined as `sys_os_version`. Also defined in this file is a `sys_compile_time`.

You can print these out by running the following at the prompt.

```
C:/Home> sys_os_version;
0.000012s ansf= 5.0300000
C:/Home> "%D %T", sys_compile_time, sys_compile_time;
05/07/18  23:53:280.000009s
```

### `Registry.HC.Z`

`Ed("~/Registry.HC.Z");` (absolute path `C:\Home/Registry.HC.Z`) and under `Adam` → `SysRegVer`,

[[image: Screen Shot of Registry.HC.Z[2]]